# Authorization when using microsoft graph api to upload a file to onedrive

Tags: javascript, reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm using the following code to upload a file to my MS teams onedrive:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import * as microsoftTeams from "@microsoft/teams-js";

class Tab extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      context: {}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      microsoftTeams.getContext(resolve);
    })
    fetch('https://graph.microsoft.com/sites/OpenSesameTest/Shared%20Documents/General/FileB.txt:/', {        
      method: 'PUT',
      body: "Hello World",
      headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'localhost', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT', 'Authorization': 'bearer'}
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => {
      console.log('Success:', result);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
  }
  
  render() {  
      return (     
        <form>
          <div>
            <label>Select file to upload</label>
            <input type="file"></input>
          </div>
          <button type="submit">Upload</button>
        </form>     
      );
    }
  }

export default Tab;
```

But I am getting a 401 unauthorized error, because I am not passing along a token. How do I authorize the PUT an actually upload the file?

I have no idea where to find the token to authorize the request with.

P.S. ignore the form on the bottom, its still there from trying another approach.

Comment: [Have you registered your app and got the necessary token?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/msa-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online)

Comment: @Andy i did, and cant find the token now, where can i find it?

Answer (score 0):

To get a token you have to provide an auth flow to the user and you'll get the token after the user logged and authenticated your app.
But doing this manually is rather complicated.

I'd suggest you use the JavaScript JDK for OneDrive (not entirely sure why you load the microsoft teams one, is it included there?).

If you use the SDK, it will handle user authentication and authorization and setting token.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  function launchSaveToOneDrive(){
    var odOptions = { /* ... specify the desired options ... */ };
    OneDrive.save(odOptions);
  }
</script>

<input id="fileUploadControl" name="fileUploadControl" type="file" />
<button onclick="launchSaveToOneDrive">Save to OneDrive</button>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/controls/file-pickers/js-v72/save-file?view=odsp-graph-online

Comment: I appreciate the answer but im really new to this. Im using the Teams one because i created a custom MS teams app, and im trying to upload a file from the tab within that app. However my fetch is failing because its unauthorized, so i need to figure out how i can allow the fetch to go through.

Comment: @7BitAscii I'd still advice you to use the JS SDK instead of doing a fetch, as with the fetch you'd also have to implement an authentication and authorization flow.

Comment: The problem is that i dont know how to work your code into my code yet, in order for it to actually upload something that is. I believe you when you say its better, its just a struggle for me to get that to work, and i already had to struggle to get to where i am now haha

Comment: @7BitAscii I understand. You'll have to read and work through the SDK documentation and examples though, I'm afraid.

Comment: I cant find the SDK youre talking about, im using visual studio code, and followed to tutorial to create the custom teams app. Where do i find the info on the js sdk? You linked something about a filepicker, im not sure how to use that

Answer (score 0):

You should be having proper permission as mention in [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)
then you will need get the access token:

1. [Get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?view=graph-rest-beta)
2. [Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0)

Coming to your code snippet, the graph API you are using is wrong

Correct URL is [https://graph.microsoft.com/**v1.0**/sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/**content**](https://graph.microsoft.com/**v1.0**/sites/%7Bsite-id%7D/drive/items/%7Bparent-id%7D:/%7Bfilename%7D:/**content**). Defining version is important while calling Graph API. In the headers *"Authorization"* value should be *"Bearer {token obtained from above step}"* and "Content-type" need to be define.

Example(I am using SharePoint URL instead of Id) -

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content", "text/plain");
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "text/plain");
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer {token}");

var raw = "This works";

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{tenant}.sharepoint.com/drive/items/root:/Example.txt:/content", requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(result => console.log(result))
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Refer [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) for other available requests.

Comment: Im having lots of trouble getting the token, is there an easier way to get the token? In the Azure AD perhaps? I have been trying to setup the authorization through the methods provided in your link, but i have been unsuccesful.

Comment: Which method are you following delegated or application? Could you please tell what you are not able to understand in the doc? Have you tried doing it in Postman?

Comment: Either one, but the problem is that i have no idea how to put it into my code. My code is in js but the examples are not. I also already have a componentDidMount() and i cant add another one. So i dont really know how to get the authentication going for this specific javascript context. If i had the token, i could hardcode it into my work. But i cannot find the token anywhere.

Comment: I see you have created: [MS Authentication in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68898336/ms-authentication-in-react). Lets track it there.