# MS Authentication in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm working on a MS Teams app that uploads a new file to the connected Teams OneDrive through Graph-API, but I'm unable to get the authentication going for my app.

The documentation I have found on the subject doesn't mention react at all, and so I have been unable to get the authentication working (since im very new to javascript and react and need a clear example). If I could simply find a valid authorization token somewhere then I could just hardcode that and it would do the trick.

Otherwise, how do I get the user/app authentication to upload my file to the OneDrive through Graph-API?

Here is my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import * as microsoftTeams from "@microsoft/teams-js";

class Tab extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      context: {}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content", "text/plain");
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer {token}");

    var raw = "This works";

    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: myHeaders,
      body: raw,
      redirect: 'follow'
    }

    fetch("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/OpenSesameTest/Shared%20Documents/General/FileB.txt:/", requestOptions)
          .then(response => response.text())
          .then(result => console.log(result))
          .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  }
  
  render() {  
      return (     
        <form>
          <div>
            <label>Select file to upload</label>
            <input type="file"></input>
          </div>
          <button type="submit">Upload</button>
        </form>     
      );
    }
  }

export default Tab;
```

My fetch seems to be working correctly, apart from the authentication error it is giving me.

Comment: As answered by @Ben Stobbs, you can get the token from by doing POST call and get access token, Another way: you can refer this sample for authentication flow : [graph-activity-feed -> auth-start.ejs](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/graph-activity-feed/nodejs/views/auth-start.ejs) and auth-end.ejs. Supporting doc: [SSO support for tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso)

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT the problem is writing the actual code, all the examples use regular javascript but i need react style, and im unsure how to get it the right way.

Comment: I didn't understand _react style_? You can use regular JavaScript code in react also.

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT I tried but it didnt work. I simply need an example of what the function would look like to fetch the Token. Can you show me?

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service).

Firstly, you need to register an application and generate a client secret in your Azure Active Directory. Then, you can use the **app id** and **client secret** in a POST request to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token` to get an authorization token.

You can then use this token in place of `{token}` in your code.

If you haven't already, you can register a sandbox Office 365 tenant for testing through the [Microsoft 365 Developer Program](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/dev-program).

Comment: Im really bad at converting code from javascript to react style, can you give me a rough example of what my POST request would look like?